# "The cell or chart you are trying to change is protected"

Tags: excel

I was able to  edit Excel a few minutes ago. But somehow when I click on cell, I get:

> the cell or chart you are trying to change is protected....

As it happened suddenly, I don't know the password.

I don't know what happened suddenly?

Comment: You unprotect the worksheet, and when it asks you for a password, you don't give it one.

Comment: @pnuts it asks the password which i don't know. When i provide blank, it says password supplied is incorrect ?

Comment: The cell is protected then. I've used protection a lot and, unless there's a macro you accidentally triggered, protection doesn't just turn on on it's own. You should get in touch with the person that created the workbook and ask about editing the cell. Otherwise you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue once, I tried the following steps : In tabs --> "Review" --> select the column header (which you were not able to edit) and click on "unprotect sheet".

I am able to edit after that. Hope it helps for you as well.